# Computer vision cross correlation with spacially constant increase in brightness

Tags: computer-vision, cross-correlation

If I'm taking the correlation between two images as described in the attached formula:

---

[image: Correlation]

---

Which is taken from the following online computer vision textbook: [Szelski](http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf) page 386.

This function does not seem like it would ever be reliable, since if one of your images is brighter than the other, the correlation would be higher than if the images are identical. For instance, take a look at these examples printed on a white board:

[image: Perfect Match]

[image]

As you can see the brighter image has a better correlation with the first image than an identical copy of the first image. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is the [normalized cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation), where the values are subtracted by the mean intensity and then divided by the standard deviation of the intensity.

Comment: Yea I noticed that would be much better, but I'm a bit confused as to why non-normalized correlation is even suggested. This was also the method discussed in a lecture on computer vision (screen shot here: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/3epgx).

Comment: Well, normalized cross-correlation is for example used in template matching to overcome illumination/intensity changes. But your screen shot is about disparity images. That topic is a bit different as for disparity images we take two input images that are shot at the same time and with a slightly different viewpoint. So the illumination/intensity is nearly the same and no adjustment(normalization) is needed.